# Need help with Placherel's Theorem

Tags: fourier-analysis, mathematical-physics, harmonic-analysis

We know that the law of conservation of energy dictates that the energy carried by a waveform in the time domain must equal the energy contained in its power spectrum in the frequency domain.  How would i go about showing analytically this law holds for a Gaussian waveform:  $e^{-a(x-b)^2}$ and its Fourier Transform.  I think I need to use Placherel's theorem but I'm not sure how to start the proof.